# Spring MVC: @PathVariable doesn't work with cyrillic

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop search by word system. I have an input where I type my word and submit that redirects me to the page with found results to a link like this `localhost:8080/Project/search/word` and everything works fine.

But when I try to search for a cyrillic word ('дума') it finds nothing. In the URL is presented 'дума' but in the java debugger console shows `дума` as `???????°`

That's my WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{ WebConfig.class };
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{ "/" };
}

protected Filter[] getServletFilters(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/search/word/{word}", "/search/word/{word}/page/{page}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public ModelAndView getSearchVideoByTitlePage(@PathVariable("word") String word,
        @PathVariable(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session)
```

`@RequestParam` works fine with cyrllic, but `@PathVariable` doesn't. I have read a lot of articles about this problem and I couldn't find a solution for my problem and my configuration. I tried with Tomcat connector URIEncoding but it doesn't work either.

I noticed that in my configuration for the `characterEncodingFilter` I am missing URL mapping which has to be `/*`, but I don't know how to set it.

If you think you have some solution for my type of configuration or you can suggest me another similar one and explain how it works I will be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to set the Tomcat settings connector to `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`, and then in my Controller to use URL encoder and decoder like this:

```
String decodedWord = URLDecoder.decode(word, "UTF-8");
```